# How to set entity relation mapping for two entites of same type inside another

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Example: I have a Spring Boot, HSQLB, JPARepository Project with

```
@Entity
public class LetterEntity{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private AddressEntity fromAddress;
  private AddressEntity toAddress;
}

@Entity
public class AddressEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  private LetterEntity letter;

}
```

So, each Letter have two fields of type AddressEntity. Each AddressEntity  has a field of its LetterEntity.

How I need to set the relations mappings and cascading?

Comment: Can you provide the information about how it's all organized in the database?

Comment: Hi, what exactly you need to know? This is a HSQLDB, I use JpaRepository.

Comment: I meant what is the structure of the tables? Do both `letter` fields exist in the same `outer` table alongside with `id` field, or there are other tables with them that are linked with the main one?

Comment: " Do both letter fields exist in the same outer table alongside with id field" yes like that